# Want to show a password toggle/visible button in my android app

Tags: java, android, xml

I have a login activity for my android app. Because of testing I typed in my password very often and sometimes I was not sure if its the right password so I need to delete it completely and typed it in again. I think this is not design! I've searched a little bit and found out that there is a function called `app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"`. I have tried it but it throws an error.

My code:

```html
<EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:ems="10"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:id="@+id/loginPassword"
        android:layout_below="@+id/loginEmail"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:hint="Passwort"
        android:selectAllOnFocus="false"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textColorLink="#63c3c3"
        android:textColorHighlight="#63c3c3"
        android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
        android:backgroundTint="#63c3c3"
        android:passwordToggleEnabled="true" //HERE!
        android:cursorVisible="true" />
```

But I got an error..

```
Error:(14) No resource identifier found for attribute 'passwordToggleEnabled' in package 'android'
```

Thanks for helping me :)

Comment: [You can see this for help](https://medium.com/@moyinoluwa/password-visibility-toggle-android-support-library-revision-24-2-0-98b422087e5a#.ghykethg9)

Comment: Can you not toggle the input type between text and password?

ie     `if (show) == checked, input type = text,  else input type = password`

(not bothering to type it out in proper syntax sorry)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need TextInputLayout and TextInputEditText

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:passwordToggleContentDescription="description"
    app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"
    app:passwordToggleTint="@color/colorAccent">

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Password"
        android:inputType="textPassword"/>

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a TextInputLayout, not an EditText.  EditText is a simpler UI element with fewer features.  TextInputLayout includes an EditText and various other views.

Answer (score 0):

use this library it works fine for this purpose:

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:24.1.1'
```

Example:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/txtUsername"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/user"
            android:drawableTint="#FF4081"
            android:hint="User Name"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:maxLines="1" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```